# Can I create a pandas dataframe that contains 2d arrays instead of lists?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

I have accelerometer/gyro data—series of x,y,z values for acceleration, angle, and angular velocity—that I am trying to process to produce charts. I have the charts part worked out, but I currently process them one parameter at a time and would like to do all of them in one run. The data look like this (series truncated for space):

```
import numpy as np
accel = [[-0.7437,0.1118,-0.6367],
         [-0.7471,0.1162,-0.6338],
         [-0.7437,0.1216,-0.6255]]
angle =  [[169.4366,49.4714,56.9421],
         [169.3762,49.5374,56.8433],
         [169.2828,49.6582,56.7059]]
avelo = [[-0.5493,-0.9766,1.4038],
          [0,-1.4038,0.7935],
          [0.061,-1.0986,0.2441]]
```

I would like to add these to a dataframe so I can retrieve them by iterating over the names of the parameters. However, all the examples I've been able to find for dataframes are for creating and accessing named lists (like age,height,weight for a number of people). Even searching "create pandas dataframe from multiple numpy arrays" isn't yielding what I'm looking for. In Perl this would be easy to do as a hash of arrays. I had similar bad luck searching for a "dictionary of arrays".

Is what I want to do even possible in Python? If so could someone please point me to a resource or give an example of how to put those arrays above into a dataframe (or dictionary) and get the series for a parameter back out?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your variables as DataFrame using `pd.concat`:

```
dfs = {
    'accel': pd.DataFrame(accel, columns=list('xyz')),
    'angle': pd.DataFrame(angle, columns=list('xyz')),
    'avelo': pd.DataFrame(avelo, columns=list('xyz'))
}
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    accel                     angle                     avelo                
        x       y       z         x        y        z       x       y       z
0 -0.7437  0.1118 -0.6367  169.4366  49.4714  56.9421 -0.5493 -0.9766  1.4038
1 -0.7471  0.1162 -0.6338  169.3762  49.5374  56.8433  0.0000 -1.4038  0.7935
2 -0.7437  0.1216 -0.6255  169.2828  49.6582  56.7059  0.0610 -1.0986  0.2441
```

You can reshape your dataframe with methods like `.transpose`, `.stack`, `.pivot`, ...

To access values, use Pandas indexing:

```
>>> df[('accel', 'x')]
0   -0.7437
1   -0.7471
2   -0.7437
Name: (accel, x), dtype: float64

>>> df['angle']
          x        y        z
0  169.4366  49.4714  56.9421
1  169.3762  49.5374  56.8433
2  169.2828  49.6582  56.7059

>>> df.loc[:, (slice(None), ['x', 'y'])]
    accel             angle            avelo        
        x       y         x        y       x       y
0 -0.7437  0.1118  169.4366  49.4714 -0.5493 -0.9766
1 -0.7471  0.1162  169.3762  49.5374  0.0000 -1.4038
2 -0.7437  0.1216  169.2828  49.6582  0.0610 -1.0986
```

Read more on [how to use MultiIndexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, thanks! So how would I retrieve just the x,y,z values for accel (for example)? Again, all the examples I find assume lists.

Comment: @Steve `df['accel']` for all of them or e.g. `df[('accel', 'x')]` for just the `x` values

Comment: @Steve. I updated my answer and give you some examples on how to slice your dataframe.

Comment: Guys thanks for all the help. One question: Why is the pd.concat method necessary, and what does axis=1 refer to.

Comment: Because you have 3 dataframes so you need to create only one along the index axis (wide format) that's why you have to use `axis=1`. If you want to concatenate along the column axis (long format), you should use `axis=0`.